# Automatic authentication for Rails dbconsole for PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I have the following problem:

- I use the command `rails dbconsole` quite often.
- Every time I do that for my production database, I have to enter a password.
- My password is a long string that I have to look up and copy paste every time.

It feels like it should be possible to circumvent that and have rails automatically authenticate. But I haven't found anything useful for this. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: PostgreSQL (see title)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Postgres

`pgpass` utility will be helpful https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html, which allows you to specify credentials for remote databases (your production instance) in a .pgpass file on your local computer so you don't have to re-type when connecting each time.

Not sure it works directly with the Rails, but if your are running `dbconsole` then it's equivalent to just using `psql`, and specifying a few more options (user, dbname, etc.) and aliasing that.

## MySQL

Similar to .pgpass, MySQL has a similar configuration file that can be specified: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-config-editor.html.

See also: https://serverfault.com/questions/120170/mysql-equivalent-to-pgpass-or-automatic-authentication-in-a-cron-job-for-mysql

Comment: The .pgpass file didn't work for ```rails dbconsole``` (i.e. I still had to enter a password), but it did work for just running ```psql```, which is almost as good for me.

Comment: Postgres also looks at the `PGPASSFILE` environment variable. I've verified that you can make that work. Create a file named `pgpassfile` for example. It should have 1 line in the following format: `db_host:5432:db_name:db_user:db_password`. Make sure others can't read the file: `chmod 0600 pgpassfile`. Set `PGPASSFILE` to the path to that file: `export PGPASSFILE="$PWD/pgpassfile"`. Now you should be able to run `rails dbconsole` without a password.

Answer (score 0):

Use `rails dbconsole -p` for older Rails versions. It should supply the password automatically. In recent Rails versions (7, maybe also 6.1) this is the default. But not so in older versions.

See: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/45810

Comment: The Rails maintainers will NOT make `-p` the default, because it may expose the password to other users on your system. See [this PR comment](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/45810#issuecomment-1247434729) and  [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/0abf0da0016abc455145810d7060a10e0b56b0b6).

Comment: @CraigBuchek, hmm, there seems to be some back and forth decisions. I hope at the end the security concerns will be fixed by supplying passwords via temporary option files instead of avoiding responsibility.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be easily fixable. If you put the password in the arguments passed to `exec`, it's exposed. If you put it in an environment variable, it could be exposed. The only remaining secure alternative is to save the password to a file, like the accepted answer suggests. But it's doubtful that all supported DBs have that functionality.

Comment: @CraigBuchek, idk if all support. But perhaps 90+% use mysql and postgres. Should we live in the stone age because of certain vendors starting with "o" or "m" prefer to do things in their own f.ine way torturing their poor users in the process? Maybe `rails db` could check for a `secure_password` flag in the adapter to determine whether automatic password should be used or not? There are solutions if one wants.

Comment: I suspect that the Rails maintainers don't think it's worth all the effort just to make it so you don't have to add a `-p`.

Comment: @CraigBuchek, if they believe protecting lazy devs is important not to make `-p` a default, then probably they would do. But I think it is not hard to be added by somebody not a core rails developer. This is open source. Anybody who is bugged enough from this behavior may create a pull request.

Comment: You're welcome to try. It seems to be quite a heavy lift though.